# XSD Restrictions/Facets for XML with element with multiple enumeration

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to write an XSD for a system with the following xml

```
<Import ID="123">
    <Attribute Name="Name" Value="Test123" />
    <Attribute Name="Date" Value="2019-04-21T22:00:00Z" />
</Import>
```

The Attribute element can have multiple enumerations, each different enumerations can have a different data type

Is it possible to set XSD Restrictions/Facets, so that

- Attribute of Name="Date" enforces date/time format
- Attribute of Name="Name" enforces string

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, no this is not possible.

In XSD 1.1 you can do it using "conditional type assignment" where the type of attribute `@Value` depends on the value of attribute `@Name`. Look for `xs:alternative` in the spec. But first check that you are able to use an XSD 1.1 schema processor.